# PHP PDO SSL MySQL connection fails

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, pdo

I'm trying to develop a PHP application which connects to a MySQL server using SSL.
I tried using mysql_connect and works fine, but with PDO it does not. When I try to connect I get the following error:

> PDO::__construct(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto

What looks strange is that if I tweak cert paths (to point to non existent files) I get the same error!

I'm using php 5.3.10 on Debian Squeeze, the following packages are installed:

```
php5-cgi 
php5-cli
php5-common
php5-fpm
php5-gd
php5-mcrypt
php5-mysql
php5-suhosin
```

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55848), although it seems quite ambiguous to me. One quote says "Note, that on PHP 5.3.8, mysql and SSL fail for me when I try to use PDO.", another one says "The PDO and SSL issue in 5.3.8 is already fixed in SVN, it was due to a typo in a 
#ifdef". I hope it helps somehow. I guess you can also apply that to 5.3.10.

Comment: I found that bug report, but I believe the typo was in the source, and was fixed in later versions, so I think it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

You need php-mysql removed and php-mysqlnd installed. On Centos:

```
sudo yum remove php-mysql
sudo yum install php-mysqlnd
sudo yum reboot
```

Ubuntu/Debian

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
sudo reboot
```

mysqli procedural:

```
$con=mysqli_init();
if (!$con)
  {
  die("mysqli_init failed");
  }

mysqli_ssl_set($con,'/ssl/client-key.pem','/ssl/client-cert.pem', '/ssl/ca.pem',NULL,NULL);

if (!mysqli_real_connect($con,'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'user', 'pass' ,'dbname'))
  {
  die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

PDO

```
$ssl = array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/ssl/client-key.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/ssl/client-cert.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/ssl/ca.pem'
        );
        try {
                $dbl = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password, $ssl);
                $dbl->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
die;
        }
```

Your certs paths must be correct. Try this in your SSL to ensure the files are there:

```
if(file_exists('/ssl/client-key.pem') && file_exists('/ssl/client-cert.pem') && file_exists('/ssl/ca.pem')) echo 'file exists';
```

The remote host (database server) must also have SSL enabled. Run the query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
```

OUTPUT:

```
+---------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                |
+---------------+----------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                  |
| have_ssl      | YES                  |
| ssl_ca        | /ssl/ca.pem          |
| ssl_capath    |                      |
| ssl_cert      | /ssl/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA   |
| ssl_key       | /ssl/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+----------------------+
```

If it's disabled, it will not work. Your /etc/my.cnf (or where your my.cnf is located) must contain:

```
ssl-ca=/ssl/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/ssl/server-key.pem
ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

MySQL Resource to generate keys: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html

Lastly, the DHE cipher is not considered safe anymore. Ciphers are continually being broke, so you'll have to find out which are considered secure today.

Comment: Thank you very much, sadly I don't have the setup anymore to test. I hope it will be useful for others

Comment: I noticed it was an old thread but it came up in Google for all my searches, so I hope others don't spend hours fiddling like I did.

Answer (score 1):

Your list of modules doesn't include include `openssl`

You can check the compiled in modules with `php -m`. And you can check all modules loaded at runtime by running `php -a` then executing `var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());`

You will need this to be either compiled in, or loaded as an extension in order to use SSL connectivity.

If the extension exists on disk (check your php extensions directory - location in `php.ini`) then also check your `php.ini` for the line `extension=php_openssl.so` and make sure it is not commented out.